# Use Different versions of Visual Studio In Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

We have to use Team Foundation Server on different machines.

Our problem is in the .csproj files where we want to check in the changes made. The Team Foundation Server warns about resolve some conflicts about different versions. Now the question is that can we use different versions of Visual Studio on different machines on the same Team Project and how it would affect our development?

Comment: What are the different versions? Are you talking 2005/2008/2010? Express/Pro/VSTS? Different VSTS editions?

Answer (score 3):

Being that the verison of Visual Studio being used is encoded into the .csproj file, it is difficult to use different versions of Visual Studio for the same C# (or other .NET) project.  Since you can install different versions of Visual Studio side-by-side on the same machine (e.g. Visual Studio 2005, 2008, and 2010), it would be best to have everyone use the lowest common denominator (i.e. the newest version of Visual Studio that everyone has) for the project.

Hope this helps.